# Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having a little trouble with `ReactJS` and `Redux-Toolkit`

I want to have a `global state` for a `Theme Switcher`. So that i can wrap a Material-UI Theme around my whole project in App.tsx. But i always get the error: `Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.`

My Store is configured like this:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { themeUiReducer } from './ui/themeSlice';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    data: combineReducers({

    }),
    ui: combineReducers({
        theme: themeUiReducer
    }),
});
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => [...getDefaultMiddleware()],
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

And my themeUIReducer looks like this:

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface IThemes {
    themeMode: boolean | undefined,
    useOs: boolean | undefined
}

const initialState: IThemes = {
    themeMode: false,
    useOs: false
}

const themeSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'themeUI',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        setThemeMode: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean | undefined>) => {
            state.themeMode = action.payload;
        },
        setUseOs: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean | undefined>) => {
            state.useOs = action.payload;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {

    }
})

export const { setThemeMode, setUseOs } = themeSlice.actions;
export const themeUiReducer = themeSlice.reducer;
```

The App.tsx file where i dispatch the reducer is configurered like this:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, useMediaQuery, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';
import ThemeSwitcher from './theme/themeSwitcher';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setThemeMode, setUseOs } from './store/ui/themeSlice';

function App() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // Get OS-level preference for dark mode
  const prefersDarkMode: boolean | undefined = useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState<boolean | undefined>(prefersDarkMode);
  const themeOption = (b: boolean) => (b ? "dark" : "light");

  const theme = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          mode: themeOption(darkMode!)
        }
      }),
    [darkMode]
  );

  const toggleDarkMode = (checked: boolean | undefined) => {
    if (checked === null)
      setDarkMode(prefersDarkMode);
    else setDarkMode(checked);
  };

  const dispatchTheme = useCallback(
    (themeMode: boolean | undefined) => {
      if(themeMode === null)
      dispatch(setThemeMode(prefersDarkMode));
      else
      dispatch(setThemeMode(themeMode));
    },
    [dispatch]
  );


  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ThemeSwitcher useOs={false} themeChanger={dispatchTheme} />
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route />
          <Route />
          <Route />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So i'll use the ThemeSwitcher later in my Navigation/Footer and via global State i'll watch the selection of the user

Answer (score 2):

Your error message tells you where to look:

> Store does not have a valid reducer. **Make sure the argument passed
> to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.**

The issue here is calling `combineReducers` with an empty object for your `data` state.

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    data: combineReducers({
        // Here is the problem. It needs a reducer.
    }),
    ui: combineReducers({
        theme: themeUiReducer
    }),
});
```

Since you aren't using the `data` property at all right now, the simplest thing is to remove it from your state.

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ui: combineReducers({
        theme: themeUiReducer
    }),
});
```

If you want to have a placeholder for a future reducer, you can provide a "no-op" reducer function which doesn't do anything.

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    data: (state = null, action) => state,
    ui: combineReducers({
        theme: themeUiReducer
    }),
});
```